# Do DIN rail mount interface relay modules with a "spare" terminal exist?

Tags: relay, module, terminal-block

I'm currently designing an industrial control panel that I'd like to be as compact as possible, and was looking at interface relays, and was hoping to find a specific feature, but now I'm not sure it exists.

Basically, I'd like a relay module with an extra connection point for the "other" wire to the actuator. ie. the relay will switch the +ve wire, but the module has an extra connection for the 0V wire. This would be bridged to all the other adjacent relay modules with a jumper bar.

The benefits would be:

- Fewer terminals - hopefully cheaper and takes up less space
- Wires from a given actuator terminate right next to each other - tidier and easier to understand and debug.

Another way of describing what I'm looking for would be to combine these two devices: interface relay module & a sensor/actuator terminal block (ground connection to the rail optional):

[image: A actuator terminal block and an interface relay]

Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Phoenix Contact FBST, it's a bar that goes in the slots under the wire connector you see on the blue relay module.

Finder will have similar. 093.16 for example. See their [catalog](https://cdn.findernet.com/app/uploads/2020/09/13082522/BRO48NL.pdf).

Keep an eye on the total current running in this bar.

---

Tip: when looking at this kind of industrial products. Find the catalog PDF! It has more seachable info than the websites. Eg: eaton, phoenix, finder. Anyone with this much products.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was looking at the Finder 39 range, and somehow missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted @Jeroen3's answer, but for those looking for the actual product I've selected:

Finder 39.51.0.024.0060

- 39 series, the MasterOUTPUT modules
- relay (not solid-state)
- push-in terminals
- 24V AC/DC coil
- AgNi contacts

- 93.16 as a commoning bar